# Giving shape with clip-path: polygon

Tags: css

I've been working on something with this clip-path, I have it almost done, let me explain you

see this image

[image]

as you see there is an inclined effect which is what I want, so far looks good but that effect was applied to the image, I want the same effect but on the first item of the list below of the image.

in order to get something like this

[image]

[here is a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/puxavoveci/2/edit?html,css,output) with what I have so far, just in case you want to taste it

and here my code

```
<div class="polygon">
  <img src="http://urbanetradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/banner.jpg">
</div>
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <a ng-href="#/tabs/news/{{post.ID}}">
    <h2><span ng-bind-html="post.title"></span></h2>
    <p ng-bind-html="post.excerpt"></p>
    <p></i> {{:: post.date | date}}</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.polygon {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 0 65%);
  z-index: 999;
}
```

and also, what should I do to put it to work in all browsers ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi sorry if i don't understand the concept of what you want and im typing anything else.

I think you can make the first child with no top border and a negative margin to get it closer to the image.

http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Clip path is not very well supported by IE

Comment: I have that effect applied directed to the image, I don't want that, I want to apply it to the first item of the list. But idk how